# Error Changing Value (Excel to CI PeopleSoft CMS)

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

In the PeopleSoft Campus Solutions module, I am using the `ADM_APPL_ENTRY1` Component Interface (CI) to fire some data.

The user account I am using is a clone of the `PS` user (i.e. full permissions). I tried with both my clone account and the actual `PS` account but it returns the same error `{ADM_APPL_ENTRY1.ADM_APPL_PROG.ACAD_PROG}(91,34)`.

I double-checked security and found all permission lists and progr security are the same for my user. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to set the row security for your user (which is not copied when you copy the PS).
If you want to, you can manually copy PS row level security on your user on:
Define SACR> Security > Secure Student Administration>Setup>User Security Replacement.
Enter your user on the search page, and enter PS on the page itself.